# Removing Android system overlay activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface, window, overlay

I have an Activity that I have set as a system overlay. I'm able to display it, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove it when I want to (via a button).

The system overlay is displayed in the Activity's onCreate() method as follows:

```
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    View mTopView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

I have a button in my Activity's layout XML file with an onClick call to method doOk(View v), which does the following:

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.removeView(v);
```

However, when I tap on OK, I get a fatal exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" and "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager"

How can I remove the system overlay activity?

Comment: The `View` passed to the `onClick` method is the `View` that was clicked. You need to remove the `View` you added to the `WindowManager`; that is, whatever `View` `mTopView` referenced.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried using the mTopView code and removing that view but still no go.

Comment: If, by "using the mTopView code", you mean you're calling `inflate()` again, that's a new, different `View`. You need to keep a reference to the first one inflated, and remove that. Make `mTopView` a field in your `Activity` class. That is, declare it outside of any method.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. However, all I get is an empty layout. I would like to end the activity as well. I tried calling onDestroy()  or onPause() after removing the view, but that didn't do anything. Only when I click on the back button do I go back to the previous Activity.

Comment: You don't wanna call lifecycle methods like `onDestroy()`. Those get called by the framework. To stop your `Activity`, call `finish()` instead. I'm really not following your setup, however, so I'm not sure if that'll solve that last Exception.

Comment: Thanks. finish() did the trick. 1 more thing. Since I have  set FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, shouldn't touch events be ignored by my Activity, and relayed to the underlying Window beneath it? I don't see this happening. I've also tried setting PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT but I don't see the Window underneath either.

Comment: No, `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` just means that if you touch outside your window, the windows behind it will receive the touch events. Like if your window only covers the bottom half of the screen, touching the top half will send the events to whatever's there.

Comment: I see. How about FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE? Does that mean that any taps within the window will be relayed to the windows behind it?